Collectionview compositional layout with estimated item height with large dataSource hanging issue
If we give the low number of items in a dataSource it won't cause the hanging the issue. If we give more than 10000+ data you can see the hanging issue.
import UIComponents

class TextViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let textView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.isScrollEnabled = false
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tv
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(textView)
        textView.pin()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // Configure the cell with text
    func configure(with text: String) {
        textView.text = text
    }
}

func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .estimated(50)
    )
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .estimated(50)
    )
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    return .init(section: section)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let texts = [
        "Short text",
        "This is a longer text that should increase the height of the cell.This is a longer text that should increase the height of the cell.This is a longer text that should increase the height of the cell.",
        "Even longer text that might span multiple lines and should show how well the estimated height works.Even longer text that might span multiple lines and should show how well the estimated height works.Even longer text that might span multiple lines and should show how well the estimated height works.Even longer text that might span multiple lines and should show how well the estimated height works.Even longer text that might span multiple lines and should show how well the estimated height works.Even longer text that might span multiple lines and should show how well the estimated height works.Even longer text that might span multiple lines and should show how well the estimated height works.Even longer text that might span multiple lines and should show how well the estimated height works.Even longer text that might span multiple lines and should show how well the estimated height works.",
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Create layout
        let layout = createLayout()
        
        // Initialize collection view
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        
        // Register cell
        collectionView.register(TextViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TextViewCell")
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
    
    // DataSource methods
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return texts.count * 10000
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TextViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextViewCell
        let textIndex = indexPath.item % texts.count
        let text = texts[textIndex]
        cell.configure(with: text)
        return cell
    }
}

This is the sample code you can run and see where the issue is caused. I think It layout the cell attributes for the each cell when scrolling. it will cause the issue only for estimated height with collectionview compositional layout. Please anyone help me out for this problem.
Thanks in advance devs.
